# Javascript string.length does not equal Python len()

Tags: javascript, python

Imagine the following text entered in an HTML `textarea`:

```
123456


7
```

If one calculates the length of this text via javascript, i.e. `string.length`, that comes out to `10`.

Now if that input's length is measured in python, i.e. via `len(string)`, it is `13`.

It does not look `13` to the human eye, but if one runs `print repr(string)` in python, we get `123456\r\n\r\n\r\n7`. That is `13` characters, not `10`. For reference, this test was carried out in Ubuntu OS.

Is there any way for python to report the string length via a mechanism that imitates javascript's `string.length's` result? I.e. in simpler terms, how do I get `10` in python?

I understand I can manually iterate and collapse `\r\n` into a single character, but I wonder if there is a more robust - even inbuilt - way to do it? In any case, an illustrative example would be great!

Comment: How are you getting the HTML `textarea` input into Python?

Comment: @KonradRudolph it is a POST request that sends data to a Django view. I check the `len` at the time of input validation in python.

Comment: Python and Javascript report the same thing the same way, put that data (with the escaped newlines) in a JS string in your console and you'll see that it reports 13 as well, so it's likely the browser normalising the submission. You can assume that the only difference is the newline, and thus can just replace the `\r` with nothing (or replace `\r\n` with just `\n`) on the python side, however you'll eventually discover that Javascript counts UTF-16 code units  while Python (2) counts codepoints, which will be an issue as soon as somebody puts an emoji in your textarea.

Comment: I also would not be surprised by browsers applying composition or decomposition *at submission*, so would again provide different data entirely.

Comment: Can you do `console.log(JSON.stringify(textarea.value))` to see if there are in fact carriage returns present. Because I'm testing in Firefox's console and JS is counting `\r\n` as two characters.

Comment: A usefull information is that browsers need to send data of forms, when use application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in post, **using CR LF**, based on doc: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Comment: Correction of my above comment: I meant to write `(3)`, Python 2 would actually report the length in UCS2 (matching JS) or UCS4 code units depending on the way it was compiled.

Comment: @xyres The Windows line breaks are coming from the HTTP response, they’re not present in the client-side data.

Comment: @xyres in my case, I get this in the console `123456\n\n\n7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Regular Expressions which is much more elegant than iterating. Replacing the characters `\n` and `\r` by `''` does the trick.

Use the re module of python.

```
import re
x = '123456\r\n\r\n\r\n7'
y = re.sub(r'\r\n','\n',x)
print(len(y)) #Answer will be 10
```

For further reference, check out the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Didn't read the question properly. I have edited the answer.

Comment: And if we have multiple, contiguous new lines, could we do something like `re.sub(r'\n\s*\n', '\n', string)`

Comment: Yup, we can. Also, re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', string) which is much more simpler. Check out [link](https://regex101.com/) for testing out Regular Expressions.